# Sending mail to a certain thread failed, even though I set headers "In-Reply-To" & "References"

Tags: go, google-api, gmail-api

## Environment

- Golang
- GmailAPI(google.golang.org/api/gmail/v1)

## Problem

When I tried to send a mail to a certain thread, with In-Reply-To and References headers set, the mail failed to be attached to the thread.

My Question: What do you think is the cause of this problem?

## Mail Header

Here I attach the header of the mail.

```
Received: from 487462728342 named unknown by gmailapi.google.com with HTTPREST; Thu, 19 Nov 2020 22:34:45 -0800
In-Reply-To: <CAMZJxVNx_GfH3mryUr78WD_N6ayz__H3=x7zTocOrWzbo+kcnA@mail.gmail.com>
References: <CAMZJxVM8vEEeuMzzMUbVirk-Mx554putqNs=HyxikWGPSy-Ayw@mail.gmail.com> <CAMZJxVNx_GfH3mryUr78WD_N6ayz__H3=x7zTocOrWzbo+kcnA@mail.gmail.com>
X-Tracking-Address: hogehoge@gmail.com
Subject: Re: Hello
To: moriwm77@gmail.com
CC: hogehoge@gmail.com
BCC: 
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============1605854084=="
Date: Thu, 19 Nov 2020 22:34:45 -0800
Message-Id: <CAMZJxVPX-6dZyNy2cSu3eAUMUZ4p-ai62uOH6=MZY7LYq6O5Lg@mail.gmail.com>
From: moriwm77@gmail.com

--===============1605854084==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"

If...

--===============1605854084==--
```

## Code

This is a adapter function to call GSuite's gmail API.

```
// SendMail send gmail.
func (api *GSuiteAPI) SendMail(token *oauth2.Token, m Message) error {
    ctx := context.Background()
    srv, err := gmail.NewService(ctx, option.WithTokenSource(api.config.TokenSource(ctx, token)))
    if err != nil {
        return handleError(err)
    }

    boundary := "===============" + strconv.FormatInt(time.Now().Unix(), 10) + "=="

    sMail := []string{}
    for key, value := range m.Headers {
        sMail = append(sMail, key+": "+value)
    }
    sMail = append(sMail, "Subject: =?UTF-8?B?"+base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(m.Subject))+"?=")
    sMail = append(sMail, "To: "+strings.Join(m.To, ","))
    sMail = append(sMail, "CC: "+strings.Join(m.CC, ","))
    sMail = append(sMail, "BCC: "+strings.Join(m.BCC, ","))
    sMail = append(sMail, "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\""+boundary+"\"")

    // Boby
    sMail = append(sMail, "")
    sMail = append(sMail, "--"+boundary)
    sMail = append(sMail, "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"")
    sMail = append(sMail, "")
    sMail = append(sMail, m.Body)

    log.Info().Msgf("%+v", strings.Join(sMail, "\r\n"))

    // Attachment
    for _, attachment := range m.Attachments {
        name := strings.Replace(attachment.Name, "\"", "", -1)
        sMail = append(sMail, "")
        sMail = append(sMail, "--"+boundary)
        sMail = append(sMail, "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\""+name+"\"")
        sMail = append(sMail, "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\""+name+"\"")
        sMail = append(sMail, "Content-Transfer-Encoding: Base64")
        sMail = append(sMail, "")
        sMail = append(sMail, attachment.Data)
    }

    source := strings.Join(sMail, "\r\n")

    var message gmail.Message

    if api.mailConfig.Enable {
        message.Raw = base64.
            StdEncoding.
            EncodeToString([]byte(source))
        _, err = srv.Users.Messages.Send("me", &message).Do()
        if err != nil {
            return handleError(err)
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

"In-Reply-To" Header and "References" Header are included in "m.Headers".
Like

```
m.Headers["In-Reply-To"]
// => <CAMZJxVNx_GfH3mryUr78WD_N6ayz__H3=x7zTocOrWzbo+kcnA@mail.gmail.com>

m.Headers["References"]
// => <CAMZJxVM8vEEeuMzzMUbVirk-Mx554putqNs=HyxikWGPSy-Ayw@mail.gmail.com> <CAMZJxVNx_GfH3mryUr78WD_N6ayz__H3=x7zTocOrWzbo+kcnA@mail.gmail.com>
```

Comment: Welcome to stack please edit your question and include your code. Without seeing your code we cant help you determine your error.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using? Moreover, are you receiving any errors when making the request?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply!I added my code!

Comment: @ale13 I received no error. I just found the mail was not threaded after I exec the code.

Comment: In addition, I found that the mails are properly threaded on other mail clients like, Spark or Mail(OSX).  It seems like they are not threaded only on Gmail client.
Therefore I guess my code has already satisfied RFC2822.
And I suspect that there are Gmail particular requirement for threading mails besides RFC2822.

Comment: The `Subject` headers must match as well in order to insert the message in the thread accordingly. Are you setting the `Subject` anywhere? @moss

Comment: Yew I set Subject header properly here.   sMail = append(sMail, "Subject: =?UTF-8?B?"+base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(m.Subject))+"?=")

As far as I can confirm threading on other mail client(Spark, Mail on MacOS), I guess this behaviour is Gmail  and Gmail API particular problem.

Comment: I found that if I set threadId on requestBody, I successfully make mails threaded. But I still have problem because it is kind of hard to get threadId, so I do not want to use threadId.

I guess that "mail from gmailAPI" and "mail from SMTP" works differently.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Managing Threads with Gmail API documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/threads#adding_drafts_and_messages_to_threads), if you want to add a draft or a message to a thread, you will have to fulfill these conditions:

> 1. The requested `threadId` must be specified on the Message or Draft.Message you supply with your request.
> 2. The `References` and `In-Reply-To` headers must be set in compliance with the RFC 2822 standard.
> 3. The `Subject` headers must match.

Therefore, the `threadId` must be specified in order to successfully insert the message.

#### Reference

- [Gmail API Managing Threads](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/threads).